# how to setup a php table to display users

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make a table that displays 5 users only and set links for the next 5 users, which will display the users from 5 to 10.I'm basically stuck at the idea at how can I do this.I don't need a code I just need to know how I will make the links that will display my users correctly, For example (if I had 32 users I should have 7 links below the table)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! A search for "php table pagination" should give you lots of good examples! like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677580/how-to-paginate-a-table-of-mysql-in-php or https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928 or https://makitweb.com/create-pagination-with-php/

Comment: dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677580/how-to-paginate-a-table-of-mysql-in-php (I voted for too broad before, so cannot close for dupe anymore...)

Comment: why when I search for those things I don't find them and then anyone show up with a link. anyway thank you both :) and sorry for making dups :(

Comment: maybe just a matter of the right keywords! It's not unusual to not find the mostly used word (like "pagination") if you don't know it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for both advice and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so you can use the **sql LIMIT** command. For example if you want users from 1 to 5, you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

After you can add a link that will reset the limit from 6 to 10 like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
```

Some people use this method to make a pagination system.